# Getting too many re-renders error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to show a FlatList, which is initially hidden, when the user clicks on a TextInput, but I'm getting an error saying that there are too many re-renders, take a look at the code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState ({
    ...
    showFlatList: false,
})

return (
    <ImageBackground source = {enterInfoBackGroundImage} style = {styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style = {styles.backgroundArea}>

                <TextInput style = {styles.inputText} 
                    onFocus = {setState({showFlatList: true})}
                    autoCapitalize='characters'
                    placeholder = {'MAKE'}
                    placeholderTextColor = {'#B2B2B2'}
                    onChangeText = {text => setState({...state, companyName: text })}
                    value = {state.make}
                />

                {state.showFlatList && <FlatList
                    style = {styles.tableView}
                    data = {make}
                    keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
        
                    renderItem = {({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.tableViewItem} onPress = {() => {
                            console.log(item.make, item.id)
                        }}>
                
                            <Text style = {styles.searchBarText}>{item.make}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </ImageBackground>
);
```

I'm only getting this error when I put `{setState({showFlatList: true})}` on `onFocus`, but when I put that inside `onPress` inside the TouchableOpacity, it worked, any kind of feedback is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you call `setState` on the `onFocus` property of your `TextInput`.

It should look more like this:

```
<TextInput
  onFocus={() => {
    setState({showFlatList: true});
  }}
  // ...
/>
```

So the same way you handled your `TouchableOpacity`'s `onPress`.